# How do I make my dropdown menu work on small screens?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu

I recently made a dropdown menu and I'm trying to get it to work on mobile screens. It works fine up to a certain point screen width but on mobile screens, it does not show. The pertinent code is as follows:

HTML/Rails view code:

```
<div class="navbar-brand logo-container">
  <a href="/"><img src="<%= image_path("banner.png") %>" class="first-logo" /></a>
</div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm p-2" id="nav">
  <div
    class="collapse navbar-collapse"
    id="navbarContent"
  >
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <%= link_to 'Home', root_path, class: "nav-link" %>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <%= link_to 'Oil & Gas', oilandgas_path, class: "nav-link" %>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <%= link_to 'Sustainable', sustainable_path, class: "nav-link" %>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <%= link_to 'Editorials', editorials_path, class: "nav-link" %>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <%= link_to 'Caribbean', countries_path, class: "nav-link" %>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <%= link_to 'International', international_path, class: "nav-link" %>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <%= link_to 'Jobs', jobs_path, class: "nav-link" %>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="d-lg-flex flex-row my-2 my-lg-0" action="/search">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" name="q" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-danger my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>

// This is the menu button
  <div class="menu-btn">
    <div class="burger"></div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

SCSS code:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {
// Navbar Menu Toggle
  .menu-btn {
    display: flex; (set to display: none on desktop and laptop screens)
  }
  #navbarContent {
    height: 0px;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 0px;
  }
  #navbarContent.responsive {
    background-color: rgb(204, 10, 0);
    flex-direction: column;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 3.5rem;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    visibility: visible;
    width: 100vw;
    ul {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      width: 100%;
    }
    form {
      position: relative;
      left: -11.5%;
      width: 75%;
    }
    input { margin-bottom: 1rem; }
  }
}
```

JS drop-down code:

```
const navbarContent = document.getElementById('navbarContent');
const menuBtn = document.querySelector('.menu-btn');

let menuToggle = false;

menuBtn.addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (!menuToggle) {
    menuBtn.classList.add('open');
    navbarContent.classList.add('responsive');
    menuToggle = true;
  } else {
    menuBtn.classList.remove('open');
    navbarContent.classList.remove('responsive');
    menuToggle = false;
  }
})
```

Any help with this would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: At what screen width, exactly, does it stop working?

Comment: @MarkMerritt It stops working under 768px.